# How to create Strips with GCP point distribution for raw GeoEye satellite imagery?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing, strip-map

I have raw GeoEye satellite imagery, I just want some guidelines for creating a strip map with GCP distribution. We need to make orthorectification for raw GeoEye satellite imagery, I think it's available in ERDAS Imagine but I don't know how I can make this.